# Why can't I "edit" (open in Interface Builder) a carbon .nib in Xcode 4.6.1?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, macos-carbon

I can't believe I need to ask this...

I'm upgrading a Carbon app from Xcode 3.4.x to Xcode 4.6.1.

When I select a .nib file in the Project Navigator, it only wants to open/ display with "Preview".  I can't get the Interface Builder Editor to display -- at all!

Obviously, there is some magic here.  Do the .nib files need to be converted to .xib first?  Or is there some component that needs to be installed that wasn't?  (I think the command line tools may not be installed).

UPDATE: I've converted one of the .nib files to .xib, and dropped it back into the project.  No difference: I still cannot bring up Interface Builder (at all).

Comment: The difference is in the format, XML IB and N IB. Try by going back to XC3 and save it as XIB instead of nib, and try again in XC4

Comment: Will try that -- but oddly, the Xcode 4.6 documentation suggests that selecting a .nib file WILL bring up the Interface Builder editor.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya -- .xib format not the answer.  I converted my Main.nib to Main.xib using ibtool --upgrade, moved the .xib back into the project, and still cannot open as anything other than Property List, Hex, Preview or Source Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 4 [does not support editing Carbon nibs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html), though you can build an app using them.  For editing the nibs, you'd better have a Mac that can run Snow Leopard, or Snow Leopard Server in a virtual machine, with Xcode 3.2.6 installed on it.

Comment: Ohhh -- OK -- that DOES explain the problem.  (I DO have a fully-functional Xcode 3.2.6 Snow Leopard environment, so I'll try it there.)  Thanks, James!

Comment: Well, are you entirely sure? On the release notes it says: **Editing Carbon nib files. Xcode 4 supports building Carbon XIB and NIB files; use Interface Builder 3.2 to edit them**

Comment: @Lefteris: Exactly, it says "Editing Carbon nib files" under the heading "Functionality No Longer Supported in Xcode".

Comment: So if you change the interface builder version to 3.2, like I'm showing on below, it won't allow you to edit it?

Comment: @Lefteris: No, that "Interface Builder Document" heading does not appear for Carbon nibs.

Comment: I see. But the way they are describing this, doesn't make this perfectly clear. At least not when I know that I can set the Interface Builder version from within Xcode for nib files.

Comment: @Lefteris, you can set the IB version within Xcode for **Cocoa** nib files.  Carbon nib files are a whole different animal.

Answer (score -1):

Continuing my answer from the reply on JWWalker's answer, on how to change the interface builder version:

[image: Interface Build Version]

Comment: Please expand your answer so that it can stand on its own. It’s hard to understand it like this.